# How can I merge new previously-uncommitted changes from a former subversion working directory into a newly imported bazaar repository?

Tags: svn, bazaar, merge, svk, bzr-svn

I had upgraded to Ubuntu server 10.04 - however it removed SVK which I had been using for distributed-vc needs, as much of my old projects were still wrapped up in self-hosted subversion repositories on various servers. This was working adequately for the time being between my various systems. I decided to migrate onto Bazaar which I was already evaluating using in newer projects.

I have installed the *bzr-svn* plugin to allow the use of *svn-import* - and successfully set up repositories in /var/bzr/repos/ where all the projects were imported into their own set (using the auto-detected trunk2 layout). bzr log confirms successful importation of all the projects.

Unfortunately, several of my projects have several uncommitted changes in a working folder - these I would like to remerge back into the central */var/bzr/repos/projectname* repository. I would like these to be new revisions on top of the newly imported repositories.

**How should I go about this?**

These working folders are i.e. /var/www/projectname/htdocs - some are on the development server, and some are on a windows laptop (which already has bazaar and subversion installed)

I have tried running bzr init and bzr merge file://var/bzr/repos/projectname/trunk - this creates a large number of conflicts; alternatively I have tried: bzr init; bzr add, and bzr merge .

In each case I have tried erasing the newly generated files from the merge - and renaming .moved files back, and committing - this has the effect of causing the revision numbers to start from 1, and running backwards to -301. Another different result was the total loss of log history when I tried to "bzr push" locally committed changes back up. Fortunately I have been able to reset and reimport the repository from the original subversion source each time.

The long route would be to simply branch/checkout into a new folder, and diff/redo the new changes over, but I would like to avoid recoding changes or running a kdiff directory merge operation.

The desired result would be to have the new changes applied onto the central /var/bzr/repos/projectname branch while preserving the revision numbers and log.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I would:
copy the .bzr dir from the branch you want to base the other changes on (mainline/main) into the workingdir with the other changes.
Then you can do a bzr commit in there and push it to your mainline/main branch.
Repeat for each workingtree with uncommitted changes.

Comment: I've tried this on the working copies on the server - and this seems to work quite well. It is somewhat trickier to achieve on laptop, but presumably if I have SFTP access to the main branch this should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you havent't commited on the bzr repository, you can commit on the svn working folder (therefore placing those changes on the SVN repository), and repeat the svn-import operation with bazaar. It will only add the missing revisions.

Comment: The svn (or rather svk) repository does not have the requisite meta data to allow committing as the server upgrade removed SVK. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Then you can create a patch file from the SVN working tree, and apply it on the bzr branch with "bzr patch"